# Why http2 doesn't work on my Apache/2.4.29?

Tags: apache-2.4, http2

I have tried to enable `http2` module on `Apache/2.4.29` which I'm running on `Ubuntu 16.04`, but it seems that it doesn't work.

I did like this:

```
sudo a2enmod http2
```

And then active individually by adding:

```
Protocols h2 http/1.1
```

I'm also running `mpm_prefork` module, could that cause a problem for `http2` and if yes what is alternative to run instead `mpm_prefork`?

One more thing I'm running shared server, which only allows PHP to run. I was checking for suPHP but it says on their website:

> suPHP is not maintained any longer and will not receive any further
>   updates not even security patches.

Comment: read conorb answer and mark it as valid, using prefork and http2 is a contradiction.

Answer (score 12):

[Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/enable-http2-in-apache-on-ubuntu-16-04) is a quick workaround that might help you out.

Also- there is some good data about `mpm_prefork` and workarounds under the troubleshooting section [here](https://http2.pro/doc/Apache)

> Starting from Apache 2.4.27, the Apache MPM (Multi-Processing Module) prefork no longer supports HTTP/2. This will be indicated in your Apache error log as follows:
>   AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved, My case with PHP, Python, Django with Apache2 with direct / proxy use, I am unable to use http2. then figure out issue and resolve as below

```
apachectl stop
apt-get install php7.0-fpm # Install the php-fpm from your PHP repository. This package name depends on the vendor.
a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif
a2enconf php7.0-fpm # Again, this depends on your PHP vendor.
a2dismod php7.0 # This disables mod_php.
a2dismod mpm_prefork # This disables the prefork MPM. Only one MPM can run at a time.
a2enmod mpm_event # Enable event MPM. You could also enable mpm_worker.
apachectl start
```

According your local you need right php version to setus, in my case its php7.0. In case you don't have PHP, just avoid php related step to follow.

Note: mpm_prefork does not well works with http2 and performance as well. my personal suggestion, use mpm_event or worker

As I setup above steps, I immediate got H2 Protocol. Your suggestion are most welcome in comment